Cant Connect With Cassandra Datastax With Django Project After Deploy It On pythonanywhere
Hi guys i work on django project connect cassandra via Datastax and evrything is fine on my machine
but when deploy project cant pythonanywhere connect with cassandra and it actually same code i used.
In pythonanywhere i work with python 3.8.10 but on my machine local i works with python 3.11
help me guys any solution?? or any platform like pythonanywhere provides python3.11 or something help my problem?
i used pythonanywhere to deploy djangoproject and use datastax for cassandra

What error messages are you seeing? Have you tried debugging this problem, at all?

You don't need Python 3.11 to run your code on pythonanywhere. I have programs written in Python 3.10 that runs on pythonanywhere. You can actually develop your web app on pythonanywhere directly without needing a local environment because it comes with a rich Python environment. So in your case, I don't think python version should be an issue.
About the database, it is important to know that pythonanywhere has built in support for only three databases: MySQL, SQLite and Postgres. The first two are available for all users whilst Postgre is only available on paid plans. Also having a paid plan let's you connect to databases outside pythonanywhere. You might want to look at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/KindsOfDatabases/

There isn't anything special about PythonAnywhere that stops or hinders connectivity to other databases or any outbound traffic for that matter. I have a project (carImageSearch) running out there on Python 3.9, connecting up to DataStax Astra DB on GCP us-east1.
How are you passing your connection endpoint(s) and credentials? If it's by environment variable (from dotenv import load_dotenv), make sure that your .env file is there and that it's getting loaded. Might want to add some debug statements on one or more of the (non-credential) env vars, just to make sure they're getting loaded.

i 've seen your gitub repo isn't like mine u actualy used astrapy python module but i use just django configurations on settings.py add database with zip file and client id & secret id credentials anyway how i can contact u sir

Yeah, no contact outside of this site, thanks.
